# How to remove Keypad when .focus() called jQuery(Kendo)

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, kendo-ui

I'm developing a kendo mobile app. There I have a text box which is forced focus by the page init. But the problem is I do not need the Keypad to be pop when Input is focused. Also I need cursor to be blink. Focus works just fine but I'm quite struggling to perform keyboard hide. Read Only I tried did not blinks the cursor.

```
function FocusText(){
    $('#f_text_box').focus();
    /*How to hide the keyboard*/
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround for this : Set Timeout works for me Tested Both on Android Web View & Chrome for Android

FocusText: function () {

```
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#input").focus();


    }, 1000);


}
```